# duplicate items loading XML to checkboxlist (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

Hi i am trying to load XML document and populate few checkboxlist. I use DataTextField as below.

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblcountry" runat="server" DataTextField="CountryofBirth">
```

And in the code behind i use this code below.

```
    Dim dSet As New DataSet
    dSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("xsource.xml"))
    cblcountry.DataSource = dSet
    cblcountry.DataBind()
```

And this is xml doc.

```
    <pupil>
    <academicYear>2011/2010</academicYear>
    <grade>Kindergarten 1</grade>
    <class>class 1</class>    
    <name>emma</name>
    <admissionDate>01/05/2010</admissionDate>
    <CountryofBirth>United Kingdom</CountryofBirth>
    <fullName>emma watson</fullName>
    </pupil>
```

It loads everything fine. But it has duplicated items. For example, if there are 5 people with CountryofBirth is United Kingdom than checkboxlist show it 5 times. If i delete CountryofBirth from 1 block of XML, it still shows a blank checkboxitem.

So my question is how do i get checkboxlist without showing those duplicated data. I am just developing a prototype (working demo) so easiest way would be more appreciated.

Thanks so much guys. I love this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down list will add a list item for every Puplil element in the XML document.  You should first filter the XML (or dataset) to a distinct list of countries and then bind to the drop down list control.

Edit w/ Linq Example:

First, remove the DataTextField="CountryofBirth" from your Aspx Page.

Second...

```
    Dim dSet As New DataSet
    dSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("xsource.xml"))

    Dim lstCountries As List(Of String) = (From dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows _
                                           Select CStr(dr.Item("CountryofBirth"))).Distinct.ToList()

    cblcountry.DataSource = lstCountries
    cblcountry.DataBind()
```

Comment: So, how do i do that? you mean something like LINQ can do the job? i tried to query a datatable before but not to a dataset. I don't think i can import Xml to datatable either. a bit of example would be very much appreciated. I am a beginner. thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much NoAlias, this is absolutely fantastic. I love the flexibility given by Linq. Especially in the organisations like mine that the databases and business logic are controlled by extremely busy database administrators. But i still can't write advanced Linq query like the one above.

Comment: Good to hear.  I love Linq too, especially for getting a subset of data without writing a loop.